# C# OleDb OUT parameter fails when calling oracle procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2013, plsql

I'm calling a procedure which has an OUT parameter (of CURSOR Type). It seems I'm missing something because I get error: "wrong number or types of arguments...". My code is as follows:

```
 public static DataTable SearchClient()
    {
        try
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(packetName + ".select_A1001310"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                                        
                cmd.Parameters.Add("io_cursor", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


                SqlManager sqlManager = new SqlManager();
                return sqlManager.GetDataTable(cmd);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex);
            //TODO; Handle exception
        }
        return null;
    }
```

PROCEDURE:

```
TYPE lcursor_data IS REF CURSOR;        
PROCEDURE select_A1001310(io_cursor OUT lcursor_data)
      AS
      BEGIN
        OPEN io_cursor FOR
        --
          SELECT client_id
            FROM a1001310
           WHERE status = 'A';
        --
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          IF io_cursor%ISOPEN THEN
            CLOSE io_cursor;
          END IF;
        --REVIRE: EXCEPTION HANDLER
      END select_A1001310;
```

### Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
If I change my code, to use OracleClient instead of OleDb, it works. Is there a way to include a Cursor Type parameter using oleDb instead of OracleClient? The OracleClient code approach is as follows

```
public static DataTable SearchClient()
{
    string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection_Oracle"].ToString();
    string procedure = packetName + ".p_search_client";

    OracleParameter[] parameters = new OracleParameter[1];
    parameters[0] = new OracleParameter("io_cursor", OracleType.Cursor, 4000, ParameterDirection.Output, true, 0, 0, "", DataRowVersion.Current, String.Empty);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = DataManager_Oracle.GetDataTable_(connection, procedure, parameters);
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Could you add your connection string? Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Connection string is as follows. `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=DB;User Id=user;Password=pass;enlist=false;OLE DB Services = -4" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess"/>
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your stored procedure returns a rowset then, PLSQLRSet must be set to TRUE in your web.config

```
<connectionStrings> 
        <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=DB;User Id=user;Password=pass;enlist=false;PLSQLRSet=true;OLE DB Services = -4" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess"/> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I included the mentioned attribute as suggested, but still I have the same issue. Now if I change my whole approach by using OracleClient instead of OleDb, it works. Is there a way to include an Cursor type parameter using oleDb instead of OracleClient? I will display the mentioned approach (OracleClient) as an update...

Comment: You were absolutely right @Nagaraj Raveendran; after some troubleshooting, your method (adding attribute PLSQLRset) worked for me. Thanks a lot friend!

Comment: Btw in order to work I had to remove the OUT parameter declaration in my code (`cmd.Parameters.Add("io_cursor",`...)